# Rank a list of numbers, allowing for ties

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have a list like this:

```
newIndexVertList = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 20, 21, 21, 20, 3, 23, 22]
```

I want to convert it to:

```
newIndexVertList = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6]
```

Here, the transformation is based on the position of number in ascending order in the original list. Hence, in the new list numbers are replaced based on the logic:

```
0   -->  0    0th position in sorted list
1   -->  1    1st position in sorted list
2   -->  2    2nd position in sorted list
3   -->  3    3rd position in sorted list
20  -->  4    4th position in sorted list
21  -->  5    5th position in sorted list
22  -->  6    6th position in sorted list
23  -->  7    7th position in sorted list
```

Below is my code to achieve this:

```
c = 0
for i in xrange(len(newIndexVertList)):
    if c < newIndexVertList[i]:
        newIndexVertList[i] = c
        c += 1
        continue
    elif c == newIndexVertList[i]:
        c += 1
        continue
    else:
        continue

# actual output:   [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 8]
# expected output: [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6]
```

What is the issue with my code? What is the elegant way to achieve this?

**Since my vertex lists will be in the 100k range, I'm looking for the quickest execution.**

Comment: `indices = [sorted(list(set(vertices))).index(v) for v in vertices]` is what OP is looking for, i think. i agree the wording of the question should have been improved

Comment: BTW, zinfandel answer will work but it is having huge time-complexity. `sorted(list(set(vertices))).index(v)` will be calculated for each iteration of vertices which performs sort, conversion to list, conversion to set + searching `v` in the sorted list

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Ah, so while it is easier to read, it may not be the fastest solution. Since my vertex lists will be in the 100k range, I should be looking for the quickest execution. Would your answer be faster?

Comment: Try it :) There I am creating `dict` once and then finding values based on hashes. Definitely it will be faster (not sure about the *fastest* part)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134520/discussion-between-redforty-and-moinuddin-quadri).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may achieve it via creating intermediate [**`dict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) object to map the number with its position in the original list via using [**`sorted()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and [**`set()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) with [**`enumerate()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> my_list = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 20, 21, 21, 20, 3, 23, 22]
>>> num_map  = {j: i for i, j in enumerate(sorted(set(my_list)))}
#                                             ^    ^ to get unique elements
#                                             ^ sort numbers in ascending order

>>> [num_map[n] for n in my_list]
[0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6]
```

As commented by [*Stefan*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann), it could be achieved in one-line using [**`map()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) as:

```
list(map({j: i for i, j in enumerate(sorted(set(my_list)))}.get, my_list))
# ^ type-cast `map` object to `list` for Python 3.x compatibility
```

Comment: Just a one-liner version: `map({j: i for i, j in enumerate(sorted(set(my_list)))}.get, my_list)`

Answer (score 3):

You've mentioned in the comments your data will be large (100k) and you're looking for the quickest execution.  You should consider using numpy:

```
>>> vertices = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 20, 21, 21, 20, 3, 23, 22]
>>> np.unique(vertices, return_inverse=True)[1]
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6])
```

For a 100k long array of integers randomly distributed between 0 and 100, this is more than 3x faster than the currently accepted answer.

Another performant option suggested by user [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) in the Python chat room, is using `scipy.stats` to rank the data:

```
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> (scipy.stats.rankdata(vertices, 'dense') - 1).astype(int)
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6])
```